# 2 SCfigure next to each other

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, captions

I want to place 2 SideCaption Figures next to each other but having real trouble with it. I tried to place them in a `minipage` and `tabular` environment but nothing worked. Always got a while bunch of errors...

```
\documentclass[
    11pt, % Schriftgröße
    DIV10,
    ngerman, % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
    a4paper, % Papierformat
    oneside, % einseitiges Dokument
    titlepage, % es wird eine Titelseite verwendet
    parskip=half, % Abstand zwischen Absätzen (halbe Zeile)
    headings=normal, % Größe der Überschriften verkleinern
    listof=totoc, % Verzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
    bibliography=totoc, % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
    index=totoc, % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
    captions=tableheading, % Beschriftung von Tabellen unterhalb ausgeben
    %draft % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
    final % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=footnotesize]{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain} 

\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}

  \begin{SCfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{android-linearlayout}
    \caption[Android Layout 1]{Android Layout 1 \cite{Google.2010}}
    \label{fig:android-linearlayout1}
  \end{SCfigure}


  \begin{SCfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{android-linearlayout}
    \caption[Android Layout 2]{Android Layout 2 \cite{Google.2010}}
    \label{fig:android-linearlayout2}
  \end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. In particular, add the package that provides the side captions.

Comment: thx egreg I enhanced the example to a MWE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem here is that the `SCfigure` environment (offered by the [`sidecap` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/sidecap)) sets a side-captioned *float*. And floats should not be contained within a restrictive environment. See the TeX FAQ entry [Not in outer par mode](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ouparmd).

One way around this is to avoid using *float* and use `\captionof` from the [`capt-of` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) (or [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)) to set a float-specific caption. Here's a little example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}% http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
% [demo] option just for this example
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{layout1}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
    \captionof{figure}{Layout 1}
    \label{fig:layout1}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{layout2}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
    \captionof{figure}{Layout 2}
    \label{fig:layout2}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This also allows you freedom over specifying the width of the caption, as well as the location.

Comment: Why avoiding floating environments here? Your example code should work fine within a figure environment (and `\caption`), too!?

Comment: @kitingChris: Note that my example sets the two figures within the text. However, as mentioned by Axel (the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) author), you can place the content inside a floating environment as well (like a `figure`).